# How to compare two dictionaries using a comprehension?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a program which accepts two dictionaries and then outputs two new ones, where the first one is going to contain elements that weren't in `d1` but were in `d2` and the other one is going to contain `d1` and then appended elements from `d2` that are not in `d1`.

**Input:**

```
dc1 = {'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 5, 'd': 6, 'e': 7, 'f': 8, 'g': 9} 
dc2 = {'e': 20, 'f': 21, 'g': 22, 'h': 23, 'i': 24, 'j': 25, 'k': 26, 'l': 27}
```

**Output:**

```
dc3 = {'h': 23, 'i': 24, 'j': 25, 'k': 26, 'l': 27}
dc4 = {'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 5, 'd': 6, 'e': 7, 'f': 8, 'g': 9, 'h': 23, 'i': 24, 'j': 25, 'k': 26, 'l': 27}
```

This is the code I've tried running however I can't understand how to properly compare dictionaries using a comprehension and create `dc3` and `dc4` in just one line. So I'm already facing a syntax error on creating `dc3`, so I haven't even started working on `dc4`:

```
d3 = {v: k for k,v in dic2 for z,x in dic1 if v: k in x:z}
d3
```

**Output:**

```
d3 = {v: k for k,v in dic2 for z,x in dic1 if v: k in x:z}
                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If anyone can help me out how to properly use a comprehension here, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: `dc1.items() - dc2.items()` and `dc2.items() - dc1.items()` works as long as there are only immutable items in each dict.

Comment: I fixed the terminology in the question to make it clearer for the future: [generator (expression)](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression) -> [(dict) comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-dictionary-comprehension)

Comment: For union: [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression in Python (taking union of dictionaries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38987/7851470)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, your syntax is a bit off. I would first assume that where you used `in dic2` and `in dic1` you meant to use `in` [`dic.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) to iterate over `key:value` pairs. Second, the `:` can basically only be in the first part of the dict-comp. I guess you meant:

```py
dc3 = {k: v for k,v in dc2.items() if k not in dc1}
dc4 = {**dc1, **dc3}
```

The creation of `dc3` just loops over the `key:value` pairs in `dc2` and only adds them if they are not in `dc1`.

The creation of `dc4` is just a [dictionary merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-in-python-taking-union-o) of `dc1` and the newly created `dc3`.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're using comprehensions, not generators.

Second, the simple "in" will handle your comparisons: you don't need nested comprehension syntax.

Try something like this:

```
{key: val for key, val in dc1.items() if key not in dc2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set operations work on dictionary views.

So given:

```
>>> dc1
{'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 5, 'd': 6, 'e': 7, 'f': 8, 'g': 9}
>>> dc2
{'e': 20, 'f': 21, 'g': 22, 'h': 23, 'i': 24, 'j': 25, 'k': 26, 'l': 27}
```

You can get what keys are common to both:

```
>>> dc1.keys() & dc2.keys()
{'e', 'f', 'g'}
```

And what keys are unique to each:

```
>>> dc1.keys() - dc2.keys()
{'b', 'a', 'd', 'c'}
>>> dc2.keys() - dc1.keys()
{'i', 'h', 'l', 'k', 'j'}
```

The same will work for keys and value (so long as the values are immutable; keys are by definition immutable):

```
>>> dc1.items() - dc2.items()
{('d', 6), ('e', 7), ('a', 3), ('f', 8), ('g', 9), ('c', 5), ('b', 4)}
```

So your output is:

```
>>> {k:v for k,v in dc2.items() if k in dc2.keys()-dc1.keys()}
{'h': 23, 'i': 24, 'j': 25, 'k': 26, 'l': 27}
```

and with Python 3.9:

```
>>> dc1 | dc2
{'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 5, 'd': 6, 'e': 20, 'f': 21, 'g': 22, 'h': 23, 'i': 24, 'j': 25, 'k': 26, 'l': 27}
```

Or with earlier:

```
>>> {**dc1, **dc2}
{'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 5, 'd': 6, 'e': 20, 'f': 21, 'g': 22, 'h': 23, 'i': 24, 'j': 25, 'k': 26, 'l': 27}
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess what you want is :

```
d3 = {v: k for k,v in dic6 for z,x in dic5 if k in z}
```

The `:` syntax is used for creating dict entries

Comment: `k, v in dic6` won't work because iterating over a dict gets keys, not key-value pairs. Use `.items()` instead. As well, `if k in z` only works in this case since the keys are strings, but either way, you don't need to iterate over `dic5` when you could just check membership. `d3 = {v: k for k, v in dic6.items() if k in dic5}`